# Do we say "pull the canopy close" or "pull the canopy closed" or "pull the canopy shut"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

in The dictionary, "**close**" is an adjective, "**closed**" is also an adjective, "**shut**" is an adjective and it is the synonym of "**closed**"

[close](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/close)

> 14 WITH LITTLE SPACE
>   with little or no space around something or between things
>   The horses are always eager for exercise after the close confinement of the stables.
>   The shoe is a close fit (=there is no space around the foot).
>   I find it difficult to read such close print (=with letters printed so close together).

---

[closed](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/closed)

> closed /kləʊzd $ kloʊzd/ ●●● S3 adjective
>   1 not open SYN shut OPP open
>    Make sure all the windows are closed.
>   She kept her eyes tightly closed.

---

[shut](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/shut)

> shut2 ●●● S3 adjective [not before noun]
>   1 not open SYN closed
>   Is the door shut properly?
>   She kept the windows shut, for fear of burglars.
>   He sat with his eyes shut.
>   The windows were tightly shut.
>   slam/bang/swing etc shut.
>   The door slammed shut behind him.
>   pull/kick/slam etc something shut  Jenny pulled the window shut.

---

[o‧pen](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/open)

> 1 /ˈəʊpən $ ˈoʊ-/ ●●● S1 W1   adjective
>   1 DOOR/CONTAINER ETC not closed, so that things, people, air etc can go in and out or be put in and out OPP closed, shut
>   He threw the door open and ran down the stairs.
>   an open window
>   The gates swung silently open.
>   The bar door flew open and a noisy group burst in.
>   All the windows were wide open (=completely open).
>   She looked at the open suitcase with surprise.
>   There was an open bottle of wine on the table.

---

[pull](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/pull)

> 1 MOVE SOMETHING TOWARDS YOU [intransitive, transitive] to use your hands to make something or someone move towards you or in the direction that your hands are moving OPP push
>   Mom! Davey’s pulling my hair!
>   pull somebody/something into/away from/over etc something
>   He pulled her down into her seat.
>   pull something open/shut
>   She pulled open the door and hurried inside.

So, do we say  "**pull the canopy of the stroller close**" or "**pull the canopy of the stroller closed**" or "**pull the canopy of the stroller shut**"?

[Ngram of "pull the door closed, pull the door close, pull the door shut"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pull%20the%20door%20closed%2Cpull%20the%20door%20close%2C%20pull%20the%20door%20shut&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpull%20the%20door%20closed%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpull%20the%20door%20shut%3B%2Cc0), people say "**pull the door shut**" & "**pull the door closed**" but not "**pull the door close**"

Comment: *Close* as a modifier also means near as opposed to far, so "pull the canopy close" means move the canopy near to me. You could just employ *close* as a verb: "Close the canopy."

Comment: _Closed_ and _shut_ mean pretty much the same, as you say, but _shut_ has more of a sense of _keeping something out_. If you are speaking of pulling a folding canopy into its folded position, _closed_ is probably better.